# Pandoc Lua filters: how to specify attributes for Span element

Tags: lua, pandoc

I have a Markdown document containing raw LaTeX commands. I am trying to use a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) with Pandoc (2.0.1.1) to convert the LaTeX commands into something more portable. In particular, commands that specify the language of text should be converted into spans with a `lang` attribute. The problem is that I don't know how to pass the attributes to the `pandoc.Span` constructor. This is my attempt at a filter (`filter.lua`):

```
function RawInline(elem)
  if elem.format == "tex" then
    text = string.match(elem.text, "\\textspanish{(.+)}")
    if text then
      contents = {pandoc.Str(text)}
      attrs = pandoc.Attr("",{},{lang = "es-SP"})
      return pandoc.Span(contents, attrs)
    end
  else
    return elem
  end
end
```

Sample usage:

```
echo '\textspanish{hola}' | pandoc -f markdown -t native --lua-filter=filter.lua
```

The output is `[Para [Span ("",[],[]) [Str "hola"]]]`, with no attributes on the span.

If I pass a name and/or class to `pandoc.Attr`, these come through, e.g., `attrs = pandoc.Attr("name",{"class"},{lang = "es-SP"})` produces `[Para [Span ("name",["class"],[]) [Str "hola"]]]`. But attributes I pass to the constructor never appear in the output. What is the right way to pass attributes to `pandoc.Attr`?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Pass what from where to where? You say that you cannot pass pass attributes to the Span constructor but you show that changing attributes and putting them into the span constructor end up in your output?  I'm confused

Comment: It seems that the only way to pass attributes to `pandoc.Span` is "packing" them into specific object by invoking `pandoc.Attr` and then passing that object to `pandoc.Span`.  You can do it in one line: `return pandoc.Span({pandoc.Str(text)}, pandoc.Attr("name",{"class"},{lang = "es-SP"}))`

Comment: I've edited the last sentence of my question to be more clear. My problem is that the `lang` attribute I'm passing to `pandoc.Attr` does not appear in the output. This happens regardless of whether I do it as in my question or in one line as @EgorSkriptunoff suggested. The output from the code he suggested is `[Para [Span ("name",["class"],[]) [Str "hola"]]]`, with no attributes, just an ID and a class (which I don't need). Since the `lang` attribute does not appear in the output, I assume I must be passing it in the wrong way. Thus my question: what is the right way to pass it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This used to be one of the rough edges in the Lua filter implementation; it has since been ironed out and made more user friendly, so the above example now works as expected.

### Background

Internally, pandoc uses two-element tables to hold key-value pairs. It roughly looks like this:

```
attrs = pandoc.Attr("", {}, {{"lang", "es-SP"}})
```

Of course, this is not a great way to represent pairs.  The reason for the current implementation is two-fold:

1. It mirrors how way pairs (and attributes in general) are encoded in pandoc's JSON output.
2. These pairs have a fixed order.

The last part is important when one wants to guarantee that the order of attributes won't be changed when passing through a filter.  There is no rule in Lua which determines the order of keys in a table: the Lua table `{one = 1, two = 2}` could be read back into pandoc as the attribute list `{one="1" two="2}` or as `{two="2" one="1"}`.  Now, the order of attributes shouldn't matter for most applications, but we cannot be sure.  Hence the less-than-intuitive representation.

### Current state (pandoc 2.16 and later)

The internal representation hasn't changed, but we have since improved the representation of Attr objects in Lua, extended the marshaling code, and added a Lua metatable. As a result, attribute tables are treated as expected. Furthermore, many users may find it more intuitive to use HTML-like attribute lists instead of "identifier, class, atttributes" triples. That is supported as well now:

```lua
attr = pandoc.Attr{id='some-id', class="one two", lang='es-SP'}
```

In fact, it is not necessary to use the `pandoc.Attr` constructor at all, just passing a table will work:

```lua
  return pandoc.Span(contents, {lang='es-SP'})
```