# Convertng Markdown admonition syntax to HTML, using Lua for Pandoc

Tags: html, lua, markdown, pandoc

The Markdown admonition syntax is based on https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/admonition/:

```
!!! note Important note
    You should note that the title will be automatically capitalized.
```

The Pandoc documentation is very poorly explained and badly written. I've trained myself with the following questions:

- [Pandoc Lua : how to add a markdown block around a header without losing the markdown syntax #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72844221/pandoc-lua-how-to-add-a-markdown-block-around-a-header-without-losing-the-mark)
- [Extend Pandoc with custom Markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71169269/extend-pandoc-with-custom-markdown-syntax)
- [Replace HTML tags using Pandoc Lua filter when converting from markdown to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604007/replace-html-tags-using-pandoc-lua-filter-when-converting-from-markdown-to-html)
- [pandoc lua filter to replace tex macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387990/pandoc-lua-filter-to-replace-tex-macro)
- [Pandoc Lua filters: how to specify attributes for Span element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290793/pandoc-lua-filters-how-to-specify-attributes-for-span-element)
- [Character escaping in Pandoc filter pandoc.Para Lua function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309862/character-escaping-in-pandoc-filter-pandoc-para-lua-function)
- [PandocLuaError "all choices failed" in custom pandoc writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547677/pandocluaerror-all-choices-failed-in-custom-pandoc-writer)

I attempted to build in Lua:

```lua
function Para (para)
  if para.content[1].text == "!!!" and para.content[1].text == "note" then
    return pandoc.Plain(
      {pandoc.RawInline('html', '<div class="admonition note">')} ..
      {pandoc.RawInline('html', '<p class="admonition-title">')} ..
      para.content[2].text ..
      {pandoc.RawInline('html', '</p>')} ..
      para.content[3].text ..
      {pandoc.RawInline('html', '</div>')}
    )
  elseif para.content[1].text == "!!!" and para.content[1].text == "danger" then
    return pandoc.Plain(
      {pandoc.RawInline('html', '<div class="admonition danger">')} ..
      {pandoc.RawInline('html', '<p class="admonition-title">')} ..
      para.content[2].text ..
      {pandoc.RawInline('html', '</p>')} ..
      para.content[3].text ..
      {pandoc.RawInline('html', '</div>')}
    )
  end
end
```

I would expect:

```html
<div class="admonition note">
<p class="admonition-title">Important note</p>
<p>You should note that the title will be automatically capitalized.</p>
</div>
```

#### Update 1

It almost worked, I just didn't like `para.content[number].text` because I need to surround "Important note" for admonition title and to catch the whole sentence after that admonition title for a paragraph.

```lua
function Para(para)
  if para.content[1].text == '!!!' and para.content[2].tag == 'Space' and para.content[3].text == 'note' then
    return pandoc.RawInline('html',
      '<div class="admonition note">'
        .. '\n\t' ..
        '<p class="admonition-title">' 
          .. para.content[5].text .. 
        '</p>'
        .. '\n\t' ..
        para.content[5].text ..
        '\n' .. 
      '</div>')
  elseif para.content[1].text == '!!!' and para.content[2].tag == 'Space' and para.content[3].text == 'danger' then
    return pandoc.Emph {pandoc.Str "Danger"}
  end
end
```

#### Update 2

Your answer worked, but doesn't work with two codes:

1. When no title, it looks like:

```
!!! important ""
```

But it gave an output:

```html
<div class="admonition important ““"><p class="admonition-title">IMPORTANT</p>
admonition with no title
</div>
```

You can notice `important ““"`. If I want to use `""` to hide the title, it would give an output: `<div class="admonition important"><p class="admonition-title no-title">IMPORTANT</p></div>`.

2. When I want to include one than paragraphs, containing italic, bold, `blockquote`, `code`, etc., your filter takes only the first paragraph, therefore, ignores the rest of the text. You can see the the reference: https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-markdown-extended#admonition. It should look like in HTML:

```html
<div class="admonition important"><p class="admonition-title">IMPORTANT</p>
<p> Here is the first paragraph with a <code>code</code>...</p>
<p> Here is the second paragraph with <i>italic</i> and <b>boild</b>...
<pre><code class="language-css">.css { color: black; }</code></pre>
<blockquote>
Accidit in puncto, quod non contingit in anno
</blockquote>
Julius Caesarus
</div>
```

#### Update 3

Please forgive me for failing to deliver the full CSS code for you before. Get the full code below:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Material Icons";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local("Material Icons"), local("MaterialIcons-Regular"), url("data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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") format("woff");
}

.admonition {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    position: relative;
    margin: 1.5625em 0;
    padding: 0 1.2rem;
    border-left: .4rem solid rgba(68, 138, 255, .8);
    border-radius: .2rem;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    overflow: auto;
}

.admonition>p {
    margin-top: .8rem;
}

.admonition>.admonition-title {
    margin: 0 -1.2rem;
    padding: .8rem 1.2rem .8rem 3.6rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(68, 138, 255, .2);
    background-color: rgba(68, 138, 255, .1);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.admonition>.admonition-title:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1.2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: rgba(68, 138, 255, .8);
    content: "\E3C9";
}

.admonition>.admonition-title:before {
    font-family: Material Icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 2rem;
    text-transform: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    speak: none;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
}

.admonition.summary,
.admonition.abstract,
.admonition.tldr {
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 176, 255, .8);
}

.admonition.summary>.admonition-title,
.admonition.abstract>.admonition-title,
.admonition.tldr>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(0, 176, 255, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 176, 255, .2);
}

.admonition.summary>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.abstract>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.tldr>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(0, 176, 255, 1);
    ;
    content: "\E8D2";
}

.admonition.hint,
.admonition.tip {
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 191, 165, .8);
}

.admonition.hint>.admonition-title,
.admonition.tip>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(0, 191, 165, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 191, 165, .2);
}

.admonition.hint>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.tip>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(0, 191, 165, 1);
    content: "\E80E";
}

.admonition.info,
.admonition.todo {
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 184, 212, .8);
}

.admonition.info>.admonition-title,
.admonition.todo>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(0, 184, 212, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 184, 212, .2);
}

.admonition.info>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.todo>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(0, 184, 212, 1);
    ;
    content: "\E88E";
}

.admonition.success,
.admonition.check,
.admonition.done {
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 200, 83, .8);
}

.admonition.success>.admonition-title,
.admonition.check>.admonition-title,
.admonition.done>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(0, 200, 83, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 200, 83, .2);
}

.admonition.success>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.check>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.done>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(0, 200, 83, 1);
    ;
    content: "\E876";
}

.admonition.question,
.admonition.help,
.admonition.faq {
    border-left-color: rgba(100, 221, 23, .8);
}

.admonition.question>.admonition-title,
.admonition.help>.admonition-title,
.admonition.faq>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(100, 221, 23, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(100, 221, 23, .2);
}

.admonition.question>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.help>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.faq>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(100, 221, 23, 1);
    ;
    content: "\E887";
}

.admonition.warning,
.admonition.attention,
.admonition.caution {
    border-left-color: rgba(255, 145, 0, .8);
}

.admonition.warning>.admonition-title,
.admonition.attention>.admonition-title,
.admonition.caution>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(255, 145, 0, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 145, 0, .2);
}

.admonition.attention>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(255, 145, 0, 1);
    content: "\E417";
}

.admonition.warning>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.caution>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(255, 145, 0, 1);
    content: "\E002";
}

.admonition.failure,
.admonition.fail,
.admonition.missing {
    border-left-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, .8);
}

.admonition.failure>.admonition-title,
.admonition.fail>.admonition-title,
.admonition.missing>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, .2);
}

.admonition.failure>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.fail>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.missing>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
    ;
    content: "\E14C";
}

.admonition.danger,
.admonition.error,
.admonition.bug {
    border-left-color: rgba(255, 23, 68, .8);
}

.admonition.danger>.admonition-title,
.admonition.error>.admonition-title,
.admonition.bug>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(255, 23, 68, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 23, 68, .2);
}

.admonition.danger>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(255, 23, 68, 1);
    content: "\E3E7";
}

.admonition.error>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(255, 23, 68, 1);
    content: "\E14C";
}

.admonition.bug>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(255, 23, 68, 1);
    content: "\E868";
}

.admonition.example,
.admonition.snippet {
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 184, 212, .8);
}

.admonition.example>.admonition-title,
.admonition.snippet>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(0, 184, 212, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 184, 212, .2);
}

.admonition.example>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.snippet>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(0, 184, 212, 1);
    ;
    content: "\E242";
}

.admonition.quote,
.admonition.cite {
    border-left-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, .8);
}

.admonition.quote>.admonition-title,
.admonition.cite>.admonition-title {
    background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, .1);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, .2);
}

.admonition.quote>.admonition-title:before,
.admonition.cite>.admonition-title:before {
    color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 1);
    ;
    content: "\E244";
}

.no-title
{
    display: none;
}
```

I had acknowledged of Pandoc's new Markdown syntax definition, but it is a bad idea to use `dl`, `dt` and `dd` for admonitions because they are designed for definitions, dictionaries, and glossaries. But anyway, I also tested with and without a Markdown syntax `:` and it wasn't what I expected.

With your updated Lua code, here is the result (click the image to enlarge):

[image: result]

In the second admonition, your filter didn't remove the title.

Expected:

[image: expected]

You can compare the images and understand it easily.

I prepared Markdown and HTML codes for you.

Here is the Markdown code:

````
<!-- With title -->
!!! note "Pay attention!"
    Title for notes

    some code and text
    
    ```C
    int main(){
        puts("Hello World!");
    }
    ```

    It is a good code.

    !!! danger "Be careful!"
    Title for denger
    
    some code and text

    ```python
    print
    ```

    It is not a good

<!-- Without title -->
!!! note ""
    Title for notes

    some code and text

    ```C
    int main(){
        puts("Hello World!");
    }
    ```

    It is a good code.

    !!! danger "Be careful!"
    Title for denger
    
    some code and text

    ```python
    print
    ```

    It is not a good
````

And the HTML code:

```html
  <!-- With title -->

  <div class="admonition note">
    <p class="admonition-title">Pay attention!</p>

    <p>Title for notes</p>
    <p>some code and text</p>
    <div class="sourceCode" id="cb1">
      <pre class="sourceCode C"><code class="sourceCode c"><span id="cb1-1"><a href="#cb1-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a><span class="dt">int</span> main<span class="op">(){</span></span>
<span id="cb1-2"><a href="#cb1-2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a>    puts<span class="op">(</span><span class="st">&quot;Hello World!&quot;</span><span class="op">);</span></span>
<span id="cb1-3"><a href="#cb1-3" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a><span class="op">}</span></span></code></pre>
    </div>
    <p>It is a good code.</p>
    <div class="admonition danger">
      <p class="admonition-title">Be careful!</p>

      <p>Title for denger</p>
      <p>some code and text</p>
      <div class="sourceCode" id="cb2">
        <pre
          class="sourceCode python"><code class="sourceCode python"><span id="cb2-1"><a href="#cb2-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a><span class="bu">print</span>(<span class="st">&quot;!!!&quot;</span>)</span></code></pre>
      </div>
      <p>It is not a good code.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Without title -->

  <div class="admonition note">
    <p class="admonition-title no-title">Pay attention!</p>

    <p>Title for notes</p>
    <p>some code and text</p>
    <div class="sourceCode" id="cb3">
      <pre class="sourceCode C"><code class="sourceCode c"><span id="cb3-1"><a href="#cb3-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a><span class="dt">int</span> main<span class="op">(){</span></span>
<span id="cb3-2"><a href="#cb3-2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a>    puts<span class="op">(</span><span class="st">&quot;Hello World!&quot;</span><span class="op">);</span></span>
<span id="cb3-3"><a href="#cb3-3" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a><span class="op">}</span></span></code></pre>
    </div>
    <p>It is a good code.</p>
    <div class="admonition danger">
      <p class="admonition-title">Be careful!</p>

      <p>Title for denger</p>
      <p>some code and text</p>
      <div class="sourceCode" id="cb4">
        <pre
          class="sourceCode python"><code class="sourceCode python"><span id="cb4-1"><a href="#cb4-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></a><span class="bu">print</span>(<span class="st">&quot;!!!&quot;</span>)</span></code></pre>
      </div>
      <p>It is not a good code.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: `para.content[1].text == "!!!" and para.content[1].text == "note"` is always false, as is `para.content[1].text == "!!!" and para.content[1].text == "danger"`; your `if`s can't possibly execute. You'll want to match `para.content[1].text` against something such as `para.content[1].text:match"^!!!%s+note`.

Comment: Well, your tip does not work.

Comment: @GustavoReis I use pandoc's definition list syntax and replace lua filter to javascript code.The render will happen when browser load the document.I add `:` at next line of title and tags, and pandoc read it as a whole definition list include its child admonitions.see Update 3 of my answer.

Comment: [pandoc readers](https://pandoc.org/custom-readers.html) can parse admonition syntax, but that requires to parse full markdown syntax in lua, which is more harder then my javascript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a lua filter like Python-Markdown's Admonition extension syntax.

You can use many tags(CSS class names), and Quoted title `""`

the different in this filter is you can't use indent, for pandoc do not think `!!!` should have a indent, so pandoc will render badly if you use indent.

````markdown
!!! danger notes "title"
You should note that the title will be automatically capitalized.
```haskell
--code will be rendered
main::IO ()
main = main
```

*Emph string* and **strong string**

!!! important ""
admonition with no title
````

the lua filter

```lua
function Para(para)
  if para.content[1] and para.content[1].text == '!!!' and 
    para.content[2] and para.content[2].tag == 'Space' and 
    para.content[3] and para.content[3].tag == 'Str' then
    local text = para.content[3].text -- default title is tag
    tags = text
    title = string.upper(text)
    i = 4
    -- parse tags
    while para.content[i] and para.content[i].tag ~= 'SoftBreak'
    do
      -- tags can only be string or spaces
      if para.content[i].tag == 'Str' then
        tags = tags .. para.content[i].text
      elseif para.content[i].tag == 'Space' then
        tags = tags .. ' '
      -- Quoted is title
      elseif para.content[i].tag == 'Quoted' then
        title = pandoc.utils.stringify(para.content[i].content)
      end
      i = i + 1
    end
    if para.content[i] and para.content[i].tag == 'SoftBreak' then
      body = pandoc.List({table.unpack(para.content, i+1)})
    else
      body = '' -- no body
    end
    return pandoc.Blocks( -- merge into blocks
      {
        pandoc.RawInline(
          'html','<div class="admonition ' .. tags .. '">' ..
          '<p class="admonition-title">' .. title .. '</p>'
        ),
        pandoc.Plain(body),
        pandoc.RawInline('html', '</div>')
      }
    )
  end
end
```

preview output(the first paragraph)

```html
$ pandoc test.md --lua-filter f.lua
<div class="admonition danger notes "><p class="admonition-title">title</p>
You should note that the title will be automatically capitalized.
</div>
```

you can add a stylesheet, for example `H.html`

```html
<style>
div.note {
    background-color: #24502426;
}
div.danger {
    background-color: #8c24047a;
}
p.admonition-title {
    font-family: cursive;
}
</style>
```

then run

```bash
$ pandoc test.md --lua-filter f.lua -s -o main.html -H H.html
```

### Update 2

update for empty title

@Gustavo Reis pandoc read wrong indentation before filter processing the text, so my filter can't be nesting.If you want to change this, you can try [definition lists](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#definition-lists) which can be nesting

```lua
function Para(para)
  if para.content[1] and para.content[1].text == '!!!' and 
    para.content[2] and para.content[2].tag == 'Space' and 
    para.content[3] and para.content[3].tag == 'Str' then
    local text = para.content[3].text -- default title is tag
    tags = text
    title = string.upper(text)
    i = 4
    -- parse tags
    while para.content[i] and para.content[i].tag ~= 'SoftBreak'
    do
      -- tags can only be string or spaces
      if para.content[i].tag == 'Str' then
        if para.content[i].text == '“”' then
          title = nil
        else
          tags = tags .. para.content[i].text
        end
      elseif para.content[i].tag == 'Space' then
        tags = tags .. ' '
      -- Quoted is title
      elseif para.content[i].tag == 'Quoted' then
        title = pandoc.utils.stringify(para.content[i].content)
      end
      i = i + 1
    end
    if para.content[i] and para.content[i].tag == 'SoftBreak' then
      body = pandoc.List({table.unpack(para.content, i+1)})
    else
      body = '' -- no body
    end
    if title==nil then
      title_html = '<p class="admonition-title no-title"/>'
    else
      title_html = '<p class="admonition-title">' .. title .. '</p>'
    end
    return pandoc.Blocks( -- merge into blocks
      {
        pandoc.RawInline(
          'html','<div class="admonition ' .. tags .. '">' .. title_html
        ),
        pandoc.Plain(body),
        pandoc.RawInline('html', '</div>')
      }
    )
  end
end
```

definition list example

[image: definition list example]

````markdown
notes

:   title for notes

    some code and text
    ```C
    int main(){
        puts("Hello World!");
    }
    ```

    denger
    :   title for denger
    
        some code and text
        ```python
        print('!!!!')
        ```
````

### Update 3

in this update, I use definition list in markdown(with `!!!` syntax) and replace lua filter to javascript code.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('dl').forEach(n => n.classList.add('admonition'))
    let dts = document.querySelectorAll('dt');
    for(let dt of dts){
        let text = dt.innerText;
        let default_title = false;
        if (text.slice(0, 4)=='!!! '){
            let i = text.lastIndexOf('“');
            dt.classList.add('admonition-title');
            if (i == -1) {
                i = text.length;
                default_title = true;
            }
            let tags = text.slice(4, i).split(' ').filter((x)=>x.length);
            for (var j = tags.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                dt.parentNode.classList.add(tags[j]);
            }
            if (default_title) {
                dt.innerText = tags[0] || "";
            }else{
                let end = text.lastIndexOf('”');
                if (end == -1) {
                    end = text.length;
                }
                dt.innerText = text.slice(i+1, end);
                if (dt.innerText == '') {
                    dt.classList.add('no-title');
                }
            }
        }         
    }
}
```

the markdown code

````markdown
<!-- With title -->
!!! note "Pay attention!"
:   Title for notes

    some code and text
    
    ```C
    int main(){
        puts("Hello World!");
    }
    ```

    It is a good code.

    !!! danger "Be careful!"
    :   Title for denger
    
        some code and text
    
        ```python
        print
        ```
    
        It is not a good

<!-- Without title -->
!!! note ""
:   Title for notes

    some code and text

    ```C
    int main(){
        puts("Hello World!");
    }
    ```

    It is a good code.

    !!! danger "Be careful!"
    :   Title for denger
        
        some code and text
    
        ```python
        print
        ```
    
       It is not a good
````

this CSS code is unchanged

below is screenshot

[image]

It seems that the effect of using `dt`, `dl`, `dd` is similar to using `div`

Comment: Please check `Update 2` in my question detail.

Comment: Please forgive me for having failed to deliver the full CSS code for you to ease your understanding. Please check `Update 3`. I added two images, one resulted and another expected for easing your understanding. I also prepared the full Markdown and HTML codes for easing your analysis.