# Can someone help to understand the following Markdown regex problem in JavaScript? I can't match the nested contexts to replace

Tags: javascript, html, regex, markdown

I used [@ianfun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15886008/ianfun)'s good JavaScript's Markdown admonition syntax parser from [Convertng Markdown admonition syntax to HTML, using Lua for Pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049303/convertng-markdown-admonition-syntax-to-html-using-lua-for-pandoc), but `dl` element within an admonition box interfered with other `dl` elements that are not part of the elements because of the CSS elements.

Based on [@ianfun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15886008/ianfun)'s code and on [Koen Vendrik](https://github.com/kvendrik)'s [CodePen Home
JavaScript Markdown Parser](https://codepen.io/kvendrik/pen/bGKeEE), I worked three days to simplify enough my JavaScript, using regular expressions, and then I almost found the solution. See my Regex 101 library: https://regex101.com/r/ZPbJpf/1

But it worked only for HTML file, and not for Markdown file because Codebraid Preview writes every line as a paragraph.

1. Open VSCode;
2. Use the Codebraid Preview extension;
3. Create a `_codebraid_preview.yaml` and add:

   ```yaml
   from: markdown
   standalone: false
   ```
4. Copy the whole text from my https://regex101.com/r/ZPbJpf/1.
5. Add `<script> </script>` at the end of the Markdown file. Here is my code:

   ```js
   window.onload = function() 
   {
     const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

     paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => 
     {
       paragraph.innerHTML = paragraph.innerHTML.replace(/^\s{0,3}!!! danger «([\s\S]*?)».*\n([\s\S]*?)^\s{0,3}!!!.*\n/gm, '<div class="admonition danger"><p class="admonition-title">$1</p>$2</div>\n\n')
     })
   }
   ```
6. You can test it by clicking the Codebraid Preview at the right of the status bar;
7. Check the Toggle Developer Tools by pressing Ctrl + Alt + I and select an element of the Markdown text to inspect it.

Comment: Ah, I missed `innerHTML`. I have just updated the code. It came from `innerText` or `innerHTML`.

Comment: So you could answer your own question. That is totally valid here on SO

Comment: Thank you for your info. It is still unsolved. When I find a solution, I'll post my answer.